# How to go about making a Core Tab on the Contact Summary screen view Inline instead?

Tags: smarty, javascript, contact-view

Specifically -> I'd like to see what's in the Membership Tab -> Inline instead. I'd like that table with Active Memberships printed right at the top underneath the Display Name on civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=xxx

When you add a Custom Data Set/Field you get a choice between Tab and Inline. Which is very cool. But how to go about switching a Core Tab -> Inline?

It's not as simple as finding the tpl - and then injecting that into the CRM/Contact/Page/View/Summary.tpl - as the $ variables aren't known. I don't really want to be copying phps bit over - I think?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than smarty, JavaScript will do the trick.  Those tabs are all separate pages, and you can load any CiviCRM page/form as a snippet instead.

First, in your extension, use a hook to include the Javascript and provide the contact ID for it:

```
$r = CRM_Core_Resources::singleton()

// Provide the contact ID (assuming you've got it handy)
$r->addVars('memberTabInline', array('contactId' => $contactId));

// Add the script
$r->addScriptFile('com.example.membertabinline', 'membertabinline.js')
```

Then in membertabinline.js:

```
CRM.$(function($) {
  $.get(CRM.url('civicrm/contact/view/membership', {
    reset: 1,
    force: 1,
    cid: CRM.vars.memberTabInline.contactId,
    snippet: 1
  }), function(result) {
    $('#mainTabContainer').append(result);
  });
});
```

You'll probably need to add a div or something and have this fill it so that you don't have the membership stuff appending multiple times, but this is the gist.

Alternatively, you might look at https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Ajax+Pages+and+Forms to see if you can fill a wrapper with the tab and have it work.  I'm only familiar with this re: popups, but it looks like it might work within any element.

Comment: Cool - thanks for this - will try this out!

Comment: I just tried this out and this works great - the entire - and I mean the entire - content of the Membership tab is now position (with .prepend(result) on my contact view page for my contactId. Learned something. Merci Andrew!

Comment: CiviCRM never ceases to amaze me ... was looking for answer on an unrelated topic and stumbled on this, thanks Karin and Andrew for this Q&A!